# Change the resource of JID dynamically without logout

Tags: xmpp

I want to know how to change the resource of JID dynamically.

For example, I sign in to a jabber service with **jeffrey@jabber.com/foo** (resource is foo)
And how to change the resource of this jid to another one such as jeffrey@jabber.com/bar without logout/login again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XEP-0193](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0193.html) provides a capability for this (in theory), but as far as I know, nobody ever implemented it.  In general, with today's servers, this is impossible.

Comment: ...and XEP-193 is deprecated.

Comment: ...mostly because nobody ever implemented it.  If someone implemented it and had evidence that it was a good idea in practice, the XEP could always be rehydrated.

Comment: [XEP-001 says it's not encouraged to implement deprecated XEPs.](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0001.html#states-Deprecated) But sure, nobody prevents you from implementing it.

Comment: I was speaking politically here.  The XSF can be talked into un-deprecating things that are shown to be useful.